# Merge two classes on screen width

Tags: jquery, html, css, merge

I want to merge two classes when my screen gets smaller than 480px. So two classes need to become one so the text is merged into 1 line. JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rMd9T/1/

This is my HTML:

```
<p class="latestworktitle">Shazam</p><p class="latestworktitle2">Redesign</p>
```

And this is my Jquery at the moment that doesn't work:

```
jQuery(function($) {

var $window = $(window),
width;

function mergeprojectitles() {
    width = $window.width();
    if ( width < 480 ) return;
    $('.latestworktitle').last().html( $('.latestworktitle').last().html() + ' ' + $('.latestworktitle2').last().html());
    $('.latestworktitle2').remove();
    }
    mergeprojectitles();
});
```

So what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Greets,

Wouter

Comment: why dont u try innerHTML ...

Comment: @Wouter125 :can you share the fiddle.

Comment: what would be the expected output?

Comment: The expected output should be only keeping 1 class, with the content of both classes in it, when i'm below 480px screensize and two classes when i'm above that amount of pixels.  Will fix a fiddle in a couple of minutes, first going to try the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your function inside resize handler:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
//your code here
});
```

Full code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(window).on('resize',function(){
var $window = $(window),
width;

function mergeprojectitles() {
    width = $window.width();
    if ( width < 480 ) return;
    $('.latestworktitle').last().html( $('.latestworktitle').last().html() + ' ' + $('.latestworktitle2').last().html());
    $('.latestworktitle2').remove();
    }
    mergeprojectitles();
});
});
```